# The best way to add a grid to a tab panel

Tags: gwt

What is the best way to add a grid to a tabpanel for gwt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[TabPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html) has two methods that

- `void add(Widget w, String tabText)`  // Adds a widget to the tab panel.
- `void add(Widget w, String tabText, boolean asHTML)` //Adds a widget to the tab panel.

With these methods you can add any [widget](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html) to the tabpanel. [Grid](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) is also widget. So,

```
    TabPanel tabPanel = new TabPanel();

    Grid grid = new Grid(1, 1);
    tabPanel.add(grid, "firstTab", false);
    grid.setSize("5cm", "3cm");

    RootPanel.get().add(tabPanel);
```

Comment: Thanks hilal! Is this the only way to do this? Instead of adding the grid to the panel in java, is it possible to do this in the xml?

Comment: what do you mean by xml ? module ? then you can't you can do it with uibinder. have a look at this http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Comment: Thank you! It would be nice if there is an existing example project for that.